# Как заставить расположить блоки рядом?

Tags: css3, css

Как заставить работать левый пример как правый только с width: auto/100% ?

```css
.old {
  float: left;
}
.new {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.own {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
.new .own {
  width: 150px;
}
.in {
  width: auto;
}
.new .in {
  width: 300px;
}
.in div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.q {
  background: #167e7d;
}
.w {
  background: #f7853d;
}
.e {
  background: #bb21e8;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
}
.clear {
  clear: both!important;
  height: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  margin: 0!important;
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="old">
  с width: auto
  <div class="own">
    <div class="in">
      <div class="q">1</div>
      <div class="w">2</div>
      <div class="e"><span>3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="new">
  с width: 300px
  <div class="own">
    <div class="in">
      <div class="q">1</div>
      <div class="w">2</div>
      <div class="e"><span>3</span>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можно поподробней описать задачу.

Comment: @Ridzhi немного изменил пример http://jsfiddle.net/YNr3b/4/ теперь видно что справа блоки расположены горизонтально. Нужно чтобы левый пример работал также как и правый, только ширина .in должна быть auto/100% а не в пикселях

Comment: Так у вас у .in и так width: auto, не ?

Comment: @Ridzhi width: auto только на левом примере, который работает неправильно. Мне нужно чтобы блоки расположились горизонтально как на правом примере, а не вертикально как на левом. Вот только нужно чтобы обязательно у .in был width: auto, а не 300px как в правом примере

Answer (score 2):

```css
.own-1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.own-2 {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="own-1">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="a">2</div>
  <div class="a"><span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="own-2">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="a">2</div>
  <div class="a"><span>3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Возможное решение для вашего примера](http://jsfiddle.net/tP9KG/1/)** (используется абсолютное позиционирование).

**html**

```
<!-- Блок div.in необязателен. Пример работает и без него. -->
<div class="own">
    <div class="in">
        <div class="q">1</div>
        <div class="w">2</div>
        <div class="e"><span>3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.own {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
}
.in div {
    height : 100px;
    top: 0;
    width : 100px;
}
/** 
 * Первому потомку ставим position: relative. Это обязательно.
 * Благодаря этому, автоматически посчитается высота для блока-обертки.
 * Высота блоков с абсолютным позиционированием не влияет на высоту блока-родителя.
 * Если внутри блока все потомки с абсолютным позиционированием, его высота равна 0
 */
.q {
    background: #167e7d;
    position: relative;
}
.w {
    background: #f7853d;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.e {
    background: #bb21e8;
    left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Для блока-обертки высота обязательно должна быть auto

Comment: @TANKIST, я обновил ответ. Теперь не обязательно указывать высоту для блока-обертки.